# infinite while while reading data from datainputstream

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, dataoutputstream

I am transferring image file from server socket to client socket while writing byte on outstream is i do close out stream after writing whole byte data on stream then it work fine but close the socket So from preventing socket close problem i am not closing the out stream from server side and then while loop is running infinite on client side while reading from inputstream.

Sending file from server side code below

```
  byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        out.flush();
  //            out.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
```

client side code reading data

```
byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "Size of image on client side" + inputStream.readInt());
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            Log.e(TAG, buf + "");
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        return false;
    }
```

So should i use any delimiter to stop while loop because what i understood is that if i don't close outstream from server so while doesn't meet with condition of -1 .

So any one help would be appreciated.

Comment: `So any one help would be appreciated.`. Can be. But then show it when people react. You did not react on most of the comments i posted. Instead you repost and repost.

Comment: do u knw the solution so tell me